# Redirect bots and crawlers in .htaccess for AngularJS pages

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using AngularJS for a webapp and have created a PHP script which generates meta rich pages on the fly specifically for social sharing purposes (not SEO indexed) using URL parameters created by the Angular route. I need to redirect search and social scraping bots to the SEO friendly generated pages.

I am currently trying to redirect http://www.example.com/v4/songs/prince/purple-rain to http://www.example.com/static/static.php/songs/prince/purple-rain for the ***scrapers/bots only***

I am using the following .htaccess code

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/1.0|facebookexternalhit/1.1|Facebot|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/static/static.php/$1 [R=301,NC]

</ifModule>

RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

I am currently getting scraping errors from all the lints saying "Invalid URL" or "No data". It works fine as a plain 301 redirect, but obviously I don't want that. What is wrong with my .htaccess file?

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem. Your "SEO meta rich pages" should have exactly the same content as you generate with JavaScript and you should just let *all* clients load that page. If all your angular code works, then it bootstraps the page and it loads faster. If it doesn't work, then the user (or bot) gets a regular page with regular links that they can follow.

Comment: In this specific case I am only needing to serve meta information for facebook/google-plus/twitter, etc. to create sharing snippets with title, image, etc - not necessarily for SEO purposes. The information on the page is very minimal. The app is a music playlist and all of the links and data is contained in angular expressions. So if the crawler can't read JS, then it only gets {{song.title}}. I realize this isn't the ideal solution (as opposed to something like prerender.io), but it is a good short-term solution for sharing songs in the playlist.

Comment: I've edited to clarify - thanks @Quentin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a second condition like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
```

?

Although you (angular route and location providers) change the urls, before angular route gets executed (which doesn't happen with crawlers) they have the #!, making the crawlers treat the rest of the path as merely parameters. With _escaped_fragment_ you can distinguish the crawlers somehow, then redirect them to the snapshot with social variables already evaluated. See [yearofmoo angular and seo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html)